# Laravel 4 not working on production server

Tags: php, apache, amazon-web-services, laravel, laravel-4

I deployed a laravel application onto an aws server in a directory that has its own domain pointing to it. However, when I go to say, example.com which points to my public folder nothing shows up, but I know that the index file is being executed. does anyone know why this could happen. This is a fresh installation of laravel 4

Any help would be appreciated.

thanks,

Joel

Comment: Do you use an .htaccess file to point to the public folder? You could always try plugging in `www.example.com/public/index.php` to make sure the index file is being executed.

Comment: Maybe there is an error and since its on prod it doesnt write anything. However, the app still dies. Try to see if you can turn errors on somewhere. (or just create an error to make sure at the start of that index file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that index.php is reached, open it and replace `$app->run` with

```
try {
    $app->run();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

You will probably now see what's going on. My assumption is that it has no permissions to write in the `app/storage` directory.

If that's not the case, turn on error display and reporting and see if anything comes up. Also make sure that the `public` folder is the document root of your application.

Answer (score 0):

try to load the site as example.com/index.php
if it runs then add .htaccess file in public folder

```
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

i has the same problem(but for laravel 5) and index file was being executed, the problems was:

```
    1. not updated php version to  required version

    2. public folder must be set as root folder
```

after resolving these points my laravel app began to work on calling server by domain name.